# google cloud function not showing any activity for invocations

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Google cloud function stopped working, is there an issue with the google cloud service ? The dashboard which shows the graph for invocations has stopped. How do debug what the issue is ?

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query

Comment: You might want to consider elaborating on "function stopped working". If you call the REST interface of your function what (if anything) is returned?  What are the details of the symptoms of the issue/story?   Could it be that no-one/nothing is actually invoking your function?  As another user posted, look in Cloud Logging to see if there are any additional logs related to the story.

Comment: What are your Cloud Logging filters?

Answer (score 1):

As an user posted, you should look into [Cloud Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query) to debug your Cloud Functions. For that purpose, set the resource type to *Cloud Function* and start looking. If you have a large amount of logs, you can set the severity to *Error* to see what is failing.

Also, if you want to check the current status of all the Google Cloud Services you can visit [this link](https://status.cloud.google.com/)